# What is the value of the measure of a line segment?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $$f(x)=1-x^2$$

Then $$|\{x\in\mathbb{R^1}:f(x)>0\}|=|(-1, +1)| = 2$$

---

Let $f$ be a nonnegative function, defined on measurable subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Then $\Gamma(f, E):=\{(\mathbf{x}, f(\mathbf{x}))\in\mathbb{R^{n+1}}:\mathbf{x}\in{}E, f(\mathbf{x})\lt+\infty\}$

By the theorem, $\Gamma(f, E)$ has measure zero.

---

Why both are just a line, the above has measure 2 while the below has measure zero?

Comment: What do you mean by "why both are just a line"?

Comment: The operative here is what Lebesgue measure you're using. In the former, you are using the 1-dimensional Lebesgue measure to measure a 1-dimensional set. In the latter, you are using the $(n+1)$-dimensional Lebesgue measure to measure an $n$-dimensional subset of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$.

Comment: This is Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The theorem says that the graph of a real-valued function defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. E.g., if $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, then the curve defined by $f$ has measure $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$; if $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$, then the surface defined by $f$ has measure $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

The first problem you post is not asking you to find the measure of the graph of a function. It is asking for the measure of the *subset of the real line* on which a certain inequality holds. That subset of the real line happens to have positive measure in $\mathbb{R}$. This does not violate the theorem, which only tells you that for each measureable $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, the set $\{(x,f(x)) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x \in E,f(x)<+\infty\}$ has measure $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Thank you. I understood what I was wrong. I need to be careful of dimensions and etc..